# Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plguin' React start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to create a React app that isn't create-react-app and I am running into some issues.  After running npm run start I received the "Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plguin'" error.  I know it's installed, as I can see it in the node modules folder.  I have tried using both npm install and yarn install for this.  I have put in in the devDependencies and the regular dependencies, and neither seems to work.  Is there something wrong with my webpack file or package.json?

Here is my webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plguin')

module.exports +{
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactboilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Webpack Redux Babel Boilerplate",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "Thomas Baric",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was easy lol.  Error became clear after seeing it as a title to my question.  FML!